# iframe resizing and closing using esc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application i want to resize iframe as On clicking "Full Screen" button iframe occupies full screen and on "Esc" key it gets into its original size.

Comment: Which part is problematic? Full screen or `ESC` key handling?

Comment: BTW: Do you **must** use `iframe` or can absolutely positioned `div` be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean full screen as in "beyond the browser window", that is no longer possible programmatically. It used to be possible in IE 4 / 5, but has since been abandoned for security reasons.

Comment: Hence my second comment on the question. :)

Comment: @Robert yeah. I'm too lazy to work out a `position: absolute` solution with a keystroke listener - if the OP is ready to accept that as an alternative, I'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Handling <kbd>ESC</kbd> button be done this way:

1. There should be no handler when the *window* is displayed.
2. When user hits **Full screen** this code should be executed to handle <kbd>ESC</kbd> key:

   ```
   $(document).bind("keydown", function (e) {
       if (e.which === 27)
       {
           e.preventDefault();
           $(this).unbind(e);
           /* restore window size */
       }
   });
   ```
3. When user hits <kbd>ESC</kbd> handler unbinds <kbd>ESC</kbd> handling as seen in the upper code and resizes the *window* back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to full screen iframe but escape is not working with this.  Any other way to fullscreen iframe on clicling button?

```
<iframe name='myiframe' id='frame' src=http://stackoverflow.com' style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:999'frameborder='no'></iframe>
```